# Assign multiple ip address to single NIC

Tags: windows, batch-file, netsh

I want to assign multiple IP addresses to my pc. I searched on google and I found a solution.

```
SET subnet=1
SET wifi=3
FOR /L %%A IN (43,1,52) DO netsh interface ipv4 add address %wifi% 172.16.%subnet%.%%A 255.255.252.0
timeout /t 4
route delete 0.0.0.0 if %wifi%
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 172.16.%subnet%.1 if %wifi%
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver %wifi% 172.16.200.81
```

But this assign ip from 172.16.1.43 to 172.16.1.52 which might be alocated to other people.

So someone, please **tell me the edits** in this script so that I can ping to IPs which are open and add that to my PC.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this? And what if a host that has one of these IPs assigned comes online later on?

Comment: I am connected to a network which has, DHCP server enabled. so I don't think that IP conflict will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but checking individual IP on my whole network with 22 mask is not possible, and setting them manually is too tiring!

Comment: Note: not all devices answer to a `ping`. Assigning the IP of such a device to your PC gets you in trouble: Your network may show unexpected behavior, slow down and even may stop working altogether.